# Dynamic number of commands parallel execution

Tags: linux, bash

I have an array with hostnames and I want to execute an other script with all the hostnames parallel. At first I did it iterative with a for-loop. But I want it parallel and I used the wait-command, but then I can't have dynamic number of hosts.

```
./sub.sh ${arr[0]} &
./sub.sh ${arr[1]} &
./sub.sh ${arr[2]}
wait
```

Now I need a function which with I can execute all the elements of the array. Do you have any solution for me?

Answer (score 3):

With **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
# Generate test data
arr=($(seq 10))

# Check it looks good
echo "${arr[@]}"
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

# Process all elements of the array - just using "echo"
parallel -k echo {} ::: "${arr[@]}"
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Other useful options, for `parallel` parameters:

- `-j N` will run N jobs at a time
- `--progress` will show a progress bar
- `-k` will keep the outputs in order
- `--tag` will tag outputs (according to host in your case)

---

In case the above is not clear in how it applies to your specific example, I am suggesting you do:

```
parallel --tag -k ./sub.sh {} ::: "${arr[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below:

```
for host in "${arr[@]}" ; do
   ./sub.sh "$host" &
done

# wait for the background processes to finish
wait
```

Comment: also - keep in mind that if you array is VERY big - this will have significant performance issues on your system